# How to judge the number of real roots of polynomials?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

If $3 a^{2}-5 b<0$, how many real roots does the polynomial $x^{5}+2 a x^{3}+3 b x+4 c=0$ have?

```
Discriminant[ x^5 + 2 a*x^3 + 3 b*x + 4 c, x]
```

I want to know how to use MMA to solve this problem.

Comment: `red = Reduce[x^5 + 2 a*x^3 + 3 b*x + 4 c == 0 && 3 a^2 - 5 b < 0, x, 
  Reals] `  gives one real root.

Comment: @Akku14 Thank you very much for your comments. Your method has solved this problem skillfully.